# Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.in only one react-native project

Tags: android, reactjs, windows, react-native, rocket.chat

I am new to React and first tried to do a Hello World Project. I got the mentioned error but also the error, that my sdk path is not set. So I configured a `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variable. Then it worked properly.

Now I want to run the rocket chat app from github on my android device. This is the project: https://github.com/RocketChat.

After navigating into the project (root), I first started the server with `npm start`, showing me a successful message. Then I wanted to run it on my phone, using `npx react-native run-android`.

This is the output I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack 
trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I know there are already some posts about this error and I tried their solutions so far, but without success yet.

My device is registered and is showing when I do `adb devices`. The global android sdk variable is also set.

What could have gone wrong? Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it. None of the solutions worked but I found another way.

First, dont forget to start the server. Navigate to the root folder of your project and run `npm start`. This should run successfully. If it says your ports are already used, just open your task manager and terminate all tasks from NodeJS.

In your android folder, run the command `gradlew tasks`. This will show you a list of available commands. I dont know why, but the command `installDebug` was not there, hence the error.

But there were other tasks which sounded similar, for example `installFossDebug`.

So I ran `npx react-native run-android --variant=installFossDebug`. But it didnt work. The console showed me a new error, saying `Task installInstallFossDebug could not be found` (No Typo).

I dont know why `install` was twice in the task, so I just ran `npx react-native run-android --variant=FossDebug` and voila, it worked. The app started successfully on my android device.

Good luck! :-)